# How to use the grep command to search all Urls in a database file except hyperlinks and http://www.example.com and store it in a different file

Tags: grep, io-redirection, file-search

I have a database file called prod_database.sql and I wanted to search all Urls in that file except hyperlinks* and http://www.example.com and wanted to store the results in a file.
Hyperlinks pattern* : `<a href="http://www.hyperlink.com"></a>`
Suppose i have a file prod_database.sql
which have below content

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://www.script.com/javascript1.js">
        <link href="http://www.css.com/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello Anwar<br/>
    <a href="http://www.anchortag.com">Google</a><br/>
    <iframe src="http://www.iframe.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I have to search all URLs which not the part of anchor tags(hyperlinks) 
in above file I should get URL from 
`<script>`, `<link>` and iframe tag only
expected result: http://www.script.com/javascript1.js, http://www.css.com/style.css, http://www.iframe.com

Comment: So you want to attempt to scrape HTML embedded into SQL for URLs, but only in some cases?  That's about as irregular as one can get.  But I'd start with `/[a-z]+:\/\/[^ "]+/` to pull out all URLs and go from there.

Comment: What is your definition of "_hyperlink_" that separates it from a URL?

Comment: Hyperlinks means Urls which are the part of anchor tags e.g. <a href="http://www.example.com">some text</a>

Comment: I would recommend first removing all the hyperlinks so that the only remaining URLs are the ones you want. For example:
`sed -E 's/<a href[^>]+>[^<]*<\/a>//g' inputfile`

Comment: Your question title mandates `grep`. Is this really an essential part of the question, or do you just mean _search using an appropriate tool_?

Comment: You mention a database SQL file in your question but the example is HTML. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The following is sort of ugly but seems to do what you want:

```
cat prod_database.sql | grep -Ev "<a href=\".*\">.*<\/a>" | grep -E "<.*=\"http:" | sed -r 's/^<.*=\"http/http/' | sed -r 's/\">.*$//'
http://www.script.com/javascript1.js
http://www.css.com/style.css
http://www.iframe.com
```

To store it in a file just redirect it to something that you want like so:

```
cat prod_database.sql | grep -Ev "<a href=\".*\">.*<\/a>" | grep -E "<.*=\"http:" | sed -r 's/^<.*=\"http/http/' | sed -r 's/\">.*$//' > somefile.txt
```

Here's the contents:

```
cat somefile.txt 
http://www.script.com/javascript1.js
http://www.css.com/style.css
http://www.iframe.com
```

Alternatively, switch around to alternative syntax/method by the following (as the user1133275 has mentioned):

```
cat prod_database.sql | grep -Ev "<a href=\".*\">.*<\/a>" | grep -E "<.*=\"http:" | perl -pe 's/^<.*=\"http/http/' | perl -pe 's/\">.*$//'
```

To store it in a file just redirect it to something that you want like so (with the updated syntax):

```
cat prod_database.sql | grep -Ev "<a href=\".*\">.*<\/a>" | grep -E "<.*=\"http:" | perl -pe 's/^<.*=\"http/http/' | perl -pe 's/\">.*$//' > somefile.txt
```

Comment: Above command is throwing an error. `sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]`

Comment: Install gnu-sed instead of relying on the minimal sed, https://github.com/pyrsmk/molt/issues/8

Comment: Installed gnu-sed and still showing the same error.

Comment: I have no idea what platform you're on. It's possible that you're mis-referencing the newly installed binary executable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @MohammadAnwar use perl -pe 's///g' instead of sed -r 's///'

Comment: Amended answer to include perl alternative syntax as not sure the original person would understand user1133275 response

Comment: Looks like OSX perl should be fine.  Ugly but hey.  Perl's a great tool when you just want it done.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `grep` with `-P` option**

`grep -o -P '(?!<.*?(?<!(href))=")https?:\/\/(?!(www\.example\.com)).*?(?=(">))' input.txt > output.txt`

Command read the `input.txt` file and write to the `output.txt` file. Change file names accordingly your needs.

#### Testing

**input.txt** (I complicated your example a bit)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.script.com/javascript1.js"><script src="http://www.script.com/javascript2.js">

<link href="http://www.css.com/style.css">one <a><a href="http://www.anchortag.com">Google</a><br/>
</head>
<body>
Hello Anwar<br/><script src="https://www.script.com/javascript3.js">
<script src="http://www.script.com/javascript4.js">

<a href="http://www.anchortag.com">Google</a><br/>some words<a href="http://www.anchortag.com">Google</a><br/>

<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
<br><br><iframe src="http://www.iframe.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.some_site1.com"></iframe><iframe src="https://www.some_site2.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**output.txt**

```
http://www.script.com/javascript1.js
http://www.script.com/javascript2.js
http://www.css.com/style.css
http://www.anchortag.com
https://www.script.com/javascript3.js
http://www.script.com/javascript4.js
http://www.anchortag.com
http://www.anchortag.com
http://www.iframe.com
https://www.some_site1.com
https://www.some_site2.com
```